# Make a SBT subproject task depends on another subproject task

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I have 2 sbt subproject, one is a CLI, one is a sbt plugin.

The sbt plugin will try to download at execution time the CLI. We have an implicit dependency here.
The tests for the sbt plugin (implemented thanks to the sbt-scripted plugin) requires the CLI to be published locally.

I usually run `sbt +cli/publishLocal +plugin/scripted`.

How can I make this task dependency explicit in sbt so everytime i run `plugin/scripted` it runs first `cli/publishLocal` first?

(FYI project source is here https://github.com/thibaultdelor/CliAppSbtPlugin)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered something like the following?

```
plugin/scripted := {
   val dummy0 = (cli/publishLocal).value
   val dummy1 = (plugin/scripted).value
   dummy1
}
```